# How to create a custom Windows 7 ISO file

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I have a customised Windows 7 that was written to USB. But I would like to create an ISO file so that i can install this on Virtualbox, as Virtualbox does not boot from USB. However when I create an ISO file using software like imgburn, the ISO is not bootable. How can I make a bootable windows 7 ISO file?

Thanks

Comment: got this working!

Comment: If you got it working, post how so there isn't just one more unanswered question sitting around.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to post an answer, otherwise I was going to.

Comment: You have to wait a few days before you can post answer to your own question.

Comment: I think imgburn has a setting to make the image bootable.

Answer (score 2):

Go here and download [Window 7 Automatic installation kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c7d4bc6d-15f3-4284-9123-679830d629f2) and copy oscdimg.exe and copy it to %windir%/system32 folder and 1 copy also to some external drives.
Now Just point out the folder location of your uncompressed window 7 folder. Or alternatively, you can uncompress the iso file to a folder by winrar utility.>br>
Now open the command propmt window and navigate to %windir%system32 folder and write following commands there to make a bootable iso from the window 7 setup directory:

```
c:\windows\system32>oscdimg.exe –bC:\win_setup\boot\etfsboot.com –u2 –h -m -lWIN_EN_DVD C:\win_etup\ C:\Win7.iso
```

where I am assuming that:
1. Your window setup files are in win_setup directory at root directory. Change it accordingly if it is somewhere else
2.you want to place the win7.iso at root drive. Change it accordingly if you want it to be crearted somewhere else.

Comment: will this tool make a bootable DVD or USB ISO?

Comment: @jiggunjer This wont produce a bootable ISO. You will have to make your  media bootable using some other tools such as [universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) etc. (incase you are using USB)

Comment: But the whole question was how to make a bootable ISO. Or is there something special like VM compatible ISOs? I don't get why imgburn wouldn't work...

Answer (score 1):

You Must Install WAIK (Windows Automated Installation Kit) for Windows 7, After this There are a few Ways to do the Same thing, One of them Being this:
Copy oscdimg.exe to root of C:, then Run This Command

```
C:\oscdimg.exe –bC:\Win7Setup\boot\etfsboot.com –u2 –h -m -lWin7Cust C:\Win7Setup\ C:\Win7Custom.iso
```

This is the Command Line, for Setup Files Located at C:\Win7Setup\ and The iso Being Created as C:\Win7Custom.iso With Volume name Win7Cust, You Can Change this Accordingly

Also, You can Run This From Deployment Command Prompt, With the Following Code:

```
oscdimg.exe –bC:\Win7Setup\boot\etfsboot.com –u2 –h -m -lWin7Cust C:\Win7Setup\ C:\Win7Custom.iso
```